# Get element of a record item by index (F#)

Tags: f#, record

I have a record, for instance with the following structure

```
 type RelativeSpeedModifier =
    { ContactSpeed: Range<Speed>
      OneThird: int
      TwoThirds: int
      Standard: int        
     }
```

What is an easy/elegent way (e.g. not hardcoded if statement) to get an element by its index

For instance in pseudocode

```
let x = { ContactSpeed: 12, OneThird: 22, ...}
let speedModifier = x.[1]
//speedModifier = 22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/indexed-properties) to type :

```ml
 type RelativeSpeedModifier =
    { ContactSpeed: Range<Speed>
      OneThird: int
      TwoThirds: int
      Standard: int        
     }
    with member r.Item (index:int) =
          match index with
          | 1 -> r.OneThird
          ...
          | _ -> failwith "out of range"
```

Comment: thx! I was not aware of this possibility!

Comment: neither was I, I have done some thing like this in other languages but this is so uncommon that it didn't cross my mind that some thing like this must exist in F#.
Edit: thanks @JLOPD

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reflection, although I wouldn't really recommend it:

```ml
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let getField i rcd =
    let info = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(rcd.GetType()).[i]
    FSharpValue.GetRecordField(rcd, info)

let x = { ContactSpeed: 12, OneThird: 22, ...}
let speedModifier = getField 0 x
```

Comment: yeah, reflection is bad, since this code is processed with high frequency

Answer (score 1):

how about destructuring

```
let x = { ContactSpeed: 12, OneThird: 22, ...}
let { ContactSpeed=speedModifier; } = x
```

I don't think you can get a property of a record by index.